# How can I make have a custom control's click activate during design time without it first having focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have a designer class for my custom control that looks like this:

```
public class NavigationMenuItemDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
{
    public override SelectionRules SelectionRules
    {
        get { return SelectionRules.None; }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;

        if (msg.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || msg.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            ISelectionService ss = (ISelectionService)GetService(typeof(ISelectionService));

            if (ss.PrimarySelection is NavigationMenuItem)
            {
                NavigationMenuItem item = (NavigationMenuItem)ss.PrimarySelection;

                item.PerformClick();

                return;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
}
```

When I click on the custom control, I want the `PerformClick()` method to fire. Which it works, but I have to click on the control twice. First to set the focus and a second time to activate the code.

When I first click on it, it looks like this:

[image]

Then when I click it again, it does what I need:

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Should I not be using `WndProc`?

Comment: Lazy answer: `item.PerformClick(); item.PerformClick(); return;`

Comment: @BlasSoriano Yeah... that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the control's click event, then determine which node the cursor is under and act on it. It looks like you're trying to handle the node's click event, which won't be fired when the control doesn't have focus.

Comment: The host control itself never comes into play. The items that you see, Home and Automation, are added at design time. So when I click on one, only it comes into play. The host control does nothing. Clicking on the item sets focus, and then clicking again, triggers the click event of the item.